# ¿Cómo guardar datos en una sesión con php y cuando recargue la página muestre los anteriores y los nuevos?

Tags: php

Quiero que me mande los antiguos datos y los nuevos pero solo actualiza la posición del `array`

```
class Arreglo
{
    private $miArreglo = array();

    function agregar($dato)
    {                                                  
        array_push($this->miArreglo, $dato);                   

    }
    function guardarSesion()
    {            
        if(!isset($_SESSION['MiArreglo']))
        {
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['MiArreglo'] = $this->miArreglo;
        }
    }
    function leerSesion()
    {            
        session_start();
        return $_SESSION['MiArreglo'];
    }
}
```

Esta es la página donde mando a llamar.

```
require "GuardarSesion.php";
$arreglo = new Arreglo();
$arreglo -> agregar(67);
$arreglo -> guardarSesion();
var_dump($arreglo -> leerSesion());
```

Esto es lo que me muestra. Cuando cambio el dato aquí solo lo actualiza en el `array` y no lo agrega como extra al que ya estaba.

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
>
> ```
> array(1) { [0]=> int(67) }
> ```

Comment: El mensaje que muestre es porque inicia la `sessión` dos veces _una vez por método_ lo cuál no es correcto. para emplear sesiones bastará con **añadir el `session_start()` al inicio del archivo.**

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que le estas diciendo que se debe modificar el valor de la variable de sesion.

```
$_SESSION['MiArreglo'] = $this->miArreglo;
```

es como decir...

```
$var = "valor";
```

intenta con:

```
array_push($_SESSION['MiArreglo'], $this->miArreglo);
```

aunque si le vas a añadir demasiados valores posiblemente te perderás mas adelante, trata de darle un nombre a lo que estas almacenando, yo lo haría así...

```
$numElem ($_SESSION['MiArreglo']) // contamos el numero de elementos dentro
$_SESSION['MiArreglo']['arreglo'.$numElem] = $this->miArreglo; // concatenamos y almacenamos
// asi utilizamos la cantidad de elementos del array como un contador
```

También podrías crear un array asociativo con la fecha de creación del array o lo que prefieras.
Por otro lador dentro de tu funcion "leerSesion()" agrega la misma comprovacion de la función "guardarSesion()", es decir:

```
function leerSesion(){
   if(!isset($_SESSION['MiArreglo'])){
      session_start(); 
   }
   return $_SESSION['MiArreglo'];
}
```

esto para que no te salga el aviso de que la sesión ya fue iniciada.
espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

El error q muestra se debe a que `session` esta iniciada. 
Coloca lo siguiente antes de la clase

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

Lo que quedaria asi:

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }

    class Arreglo
    {
        private $miArreglo = array();

        function agregar($dato)
        {                                                  
            array_push($this->miArreglo, $dato);                   

        }
        function guardarSesion()
        {            
            if(!isset($_SESSION['MiArreglo']))
            {
                $_SESSION['MiArreglo'] = $this->miArreglo;
            }
        }
        function leerSesion()
        {            
            return $_SESSION['MiArreglo'];
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje es bastante común y básicamente intenta decir que la `session` ya ha sido iniciada y que ignore volver a iniciarla. Esto en su código se refleja porque hace la llamada a dos métodos `guardarSesion()` y `leerSesion()` y en los dos inicia `sessión.`

Puede optar por dos formas para solucionar esto.

- Añadir el Inicio de `sessión` al inicio del archivo, comprobando que no esté definida o que sea null  `(!isset)` si es así la inicia

  ```
  <?php
   if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
   class Arreglo { .... }
  ```
- Añadir esta comprobación y el inicio de Sesión en el constructor de la clase Arreglo.

  ```
  function __construct()
  {
   if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
  }
  ```

El error de almacenamiento de valores en `Sessión` es básicamente porque el `array` siempre se creará vacío y solo tendrá un elemento al llamar al método `guardarSesion`, para seguir concatenando valores que se añadan podría emplear la función [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php) para combinar el `array` que se le pasa con lo que ya tenía la variable `sessión`.

```
function guardarSesion()
{            
  $_SESSION['MiArreglo'] = array_merge($_SESSION['MiArreglo'], $this->miArreglo);
}
```